# Conversion of column based record to row based record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table which contains 5 columns for instance (The actual table consists of like 100 columns).

Table name: `SuperStore` (source)

Columns:

rid (PK), OrderID(nvarchar), OrderDate(date), Address(nvarchar), CustomerName(nvarchar), Category(nvarchar)

Sample data:

```
| rid  | OrderID| OrderDate   || Address| CustomerName| Category|
|1     |00100100| 12/12/2009  || 1233   | center      | right   |
|2     |00100111| 12/12/2009  || 1234   | center      | left    |
```

I have some tens of thousand's records in this.

I need the following format to be inserted in another table

Table name: `Allrecords` (destination)

Columns:

rowid(PK), rid(FK), TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate

Sample data:

```
 | rowid| rid| TableName || ColumnName| ColumnValue | CreatedDate|ModifiedDate |
 |1     |1   | SuperStore|| OrderID     | 00100100  |            |
 |2     |1   | SuperStore|| OrderDate   | 12/12/2009|            |
 |3     |1   | SuperStore|| Address     | 1233      |            |
```

Of course I can do this through a c# program that will read the source record and insert into `allrecord`, but I want to do this through stored procedures and also I have many source tables having many columns and need to insert into the `allrecord` table. Is there a way to identify the source table columns dynamically through a stored procedure and insert into the `allrecords` table?

Comment: Obviously rowid cannot be "PK" if it repeats for every row associated with the same rid value.

Comment: To do this dynamically, see [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3002/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-dynamically-normalize-output/), though you'd have to have a way to determine what columns in any given table are the ones you need to unpivot, and what columns you don't...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for this, the only tricky part is making sure all three columns are converted to the exact same data type (I'm guessing `OrderID` can't be > 500 characters, though the fact it's Unicode in the first place is surprising, and guessing also that `Address` is limited to something less than 500 characters):

```
;;; /* for safety */ ;;;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT rid, 
    TableName = N'SuperStore', 
    OrderID   = CONVERT(nvarchar(500), OrderID),
    OrderDate = CONVERT(nvarchar(500), OrderDate, 101), 
    -- the 101 format is a guess? avoid ambiguous formats
    Address   = CONVERT(nvarchar(500), Address)
  FROM dbo.SuperStore
)
SELECT 
  [rowid] = rid, -- (assume this is generated in the target IDENTITY col?)
  rid, 
  TableName, 
  ColumnName, 
  ColumnValue
FROM src
UNPIVOT 
(
  ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (OrderID, OrderDate, Address)
) AS up;
```

Output:

| rowid | rid | TableName | ColumnName | ColumnValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | SuperStore | OrderID | 00100100 |
| 1 | 1 | SuperStore | OrderDate | 12/12/2009 |
| 1 | 1 | SuperStore | Address | 1233 |
| 2 | 2 | SuperStore | OrderID | 00100111 |
| 2 | 2 | SuperStore | OrderDate | 12/12/2009 |
| 2 | 2 | SuperStore | Address | 1234 |

You didn't explain where the additional date columns came from, but they'd be easy to add either inside `src` or outside.

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f80522e75d798e02cb73d5be9888c6b)

Comment: I have numerous columns, probably 200 such columns, I want everything to be normalised. Is there a procedure where it could take the column names dynamically from the table names using master table? I understand you have given me a solution that used all the column names, but is there a way to identify the column names dynamically without explicitly stating them?